# How can I get a reference to an operand?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Currently I have a C++ code that looks like this:

```cpp
/*
 * class declarations
 */

int main() {
    Object1 obj;

    obj->foo();
}
```

I want to make an llvm function pass that inserts an instruction to make it look like this:

```cpp
/*
 * class declarations
 */

int main() {
    Object1 obj;

    bar(&obj);
    obj.foo();
}
```

Currently, I can detect the location where I need to insert. However, I am having a bit of trouble inserting bar() function call.

Specifically speaking, in my llvm pass, I am able to get the object "obj" by from the instruction "obj.foo();". However, after creating the function, I am having hard time passing in the reference of "obj" to the function bar().

Below is my Function pass:

```cpp
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    for (auto &BB : F) {
        for (auto &I : BB) {
            if (I.getOpcode() == Instruction::Call || I.getOpcode() == Instruction::Invoke) {
                /*
                 * few more filters to get the virtual function calls
                 */

                 // Grabbing "obj" from "obj.foo();"
                 Value *currOperand = I.getOperand(0);
                 Type *currType = const_cast<Type*> (currOperand->getType());

                 // Inserting bar(&obj); 
                 IRBuilder<> builder(F.getContext());
                 Type *result = Type::getVoidTy(F.getContext());
                 ArrayRef<Type*> params = {
                     PointerType::getUnqual(currType)
                 };
                 FunctionType *func_type = FunctionType::get(result, params, false);
                 FunctionCallee bar = I.getModule()->getOrInsertFunction("bar", func_type);

                 ArrayRef<Value*> args = {
                     // I think this line below is wrong
                     builder.CreateIntToPtr(currOperand, currType) 
                 };
                 builder.CreateCall(bar, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It currently errors out at builder.CreateCall(bar. args); with following error message.

```
"Calling a function with a bad signature!" failed.
```

That leads me to believe that my "args" variable is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rewriting an AST? What's your final goal to achieve with this? A bit more context [added to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55657089/edit) would be useful to provide concise and clear answers.

Comment: try `currType->getPointerTo()` on your "wrong" line.

Comment: @MikeVine currType->getPointerTo() returns a PointerType* which is not a Value *. Here is the error for your reference: "error: could not convert ‘{currType->llvm::Type::getPointerTo(0)}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am just trying to insert a specific function call through a Function pass as you can see from my first two code blocks

Comment: @JinwooYom I mean `builder.CreateIntToPtr(currOperand, currType->getPointerTo())`

Comment: (also are you seriously still using llvm 3.0? Thats very old now. Its currently on version 9)

Comment: @MikeVine oh sorry, I am using llvm 7.0 I'll remove that tag

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I fixed the issue. I will share the solution below for all my brothers and sisters struggling with this issue:

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    for (auto &BB : F) {
        for (auto &I : BB) {
            if (I.getOpcode() == Instruction::Call || I.getOpcode() == Instruction::Invoke) {
                /*
                 * few more filters here to get the virtual function calls
                 */

                 // Grabbing "obj" from "obj.foo();"
                 Value *currOperand = I.getOperand(0);
                 Type *currType = const_cast<Type*> (currOperand->getType());

                 // Inserting bar(&obj);
                 LLVMContext &ctx = F.getContext();
                 IRBuilder<> builder(ctx);
                 builder.SetInsertPoint(&I);

                 ArrayRef<Type*> params = {
                     currType->getPointerTo()
                 };
                 Type *result = Type::getVoidTy(ctx);
                 FunctionType *func_type = FunctionType::get(result, params, false);
                 FunctionCallee bar = I.getModule()->getOrInsertFunction("bar", func_type);

                 ArrayRef<Value*> args = {
                     builder.CreatePointerCast(currOperand, currType->getPointerTo()) 
                 };
                 builder.CreateCall(bar, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```